# C++ Segmentation Fault OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

The idea in the following code is to have a bunch of "wanderer" objects that slowly "paint" an image onto a canvas. The problem is, that this code only seems to working on square images (in the code, the square image is identified as "hidden" (because it is unveiled by the "painters") and it is loaded in from the file called "UncoverTest.png"), not rectangular ones, which is mysterious to me. I get a segmentation fault error when trying to work with anything but a square. As far as I can tell, the segmentation fault error emerges when I enter the loop to iterate through the vector of type Agent (at the line `for (vector<Agent>::iterator iter = agents.begin(); iter != agents.end();++iter)`).

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//#define WINDOW_SIZE 500
#define STEP_SIZE 10.0
#define NUM_AGENTS 100
/********************/
/* Agent class definition and class prototypes */
/********************/
class Agent {
public:
  Agent();
  int * GetLocation(void);
  void Move(void);
  void Draw(Mat image);
  int * GetSize(void);
private:
  double UnifRand(void);
  int * location;
  int * GetReveal(void);
  Mat hidden;
};
int * Agent::GetSize(void) {
  int * size = new int[2];
  size[0] = hidden.cols;
  size[1] = hidden.rows;
  return (size);
}
int * Agent::GetReveal(void) {
  int * BGR = new int[3];
  location = GetLocation();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    BGR[i] = hidden.data[hidden.step[0]*location[0] + hidden.step[1]*location[1] + i];
  }
  return (BGR);
}
void Agent::Draw(Mat image) {
  int * location = GetLocation();
  int * color = GetReveal();
  for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++) {
    image.data[image.step[0]*location[0] + image.step[1]*location[1] + i] = color[i];
  }
}
void Agent::Move(void) {
  int dx = (int)(STEP_SIZE*UnifRand() - STEP_SIZE/2);
  int dy = (int)(STEP_SIZE*UnifRand() - STEP_SIZE/2);
  location[0] += (((location[0] + dx >= 0) & (location[0] + dx < hidden.cols)) ? dx : 0);
  location[1] += (((location[1] + dy >= 0) & (location[1] + dy < hidden.rows)) ? dy : 0);
}
Agent::Agent() {
  location = new int[2];
  hidden = imread("UncoverTest.png",1);
  location[0] = (int)(UnifRand()*hidden.cols);
  location[1] = (int)(UnifRand()*hidden.rows);
}
double Agent::UnifRand(void) {
  return (rand()/(double(RAND_MAX)));
}
int * Agent::GetLocation(void) {
  return (location);
}
/********************/
/* Function prototypes unrelated to the Agent class */
/********************/
void DrawAgents(void);
/********************/
/* Main function */
/********************/
int main(void) {
  DrawAgents();
  return (0);
}
void DrawAgents(void) {
  vector<Agent> agents;
  int * size = new int[2];
  Mat image;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_AGENTS; i++) {
    Agent * a = new Agent();
    agents.push_back(* a);
    if (i == 0) {
      size = (* a).GetSize();
    }
  }
  // cout << size[0] << " " << size[1] << endl;
  image = Mat::zeros(size[0],size[1],CV_8UC3);
  cvNamedWindow("Agent Example",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvMoveWindow("Agent Example",100,100);
  for (int stop = 1;stop != 27;stop = cvWaitKey(41)) {
    for (vector<Agent>::iterator iter = agents.begin(); iter != agents.end();++iter) {
      (* iter).Move();
      (* iter).Draw(image);
    } imshow("Agent Example",image);
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how this error arises with square images only and how the problem might be fixed?

Comment: You need to determine where segvfault occours. I guess is related to vector<Agent>::iterator iter line.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I speculated. In fact, after some carefully placed print statements, I'm pretty sure that's where the fault occurs. The question is: What do I do with that information?

Comment: Verify if Move() and Draw() methods is applicable for an object that exist.

Comment: So I added a print statement after the draw method was called. I supposed that if either of the methods were broken or couldn't execute, then the print statement would never appear. After recompiling an executable, the program successfully printed AND THEN threw a segmentation error. So, in other words, it seemed to be failing after that iterator loop completed. So I decided to see if print statements after imshow worked, and they did not. So the problem seems to be with imshow or with the Mat I'm passing to it. Advice?

Comment: Actually, I have to take that back. Print statements outside the for loop but before imshow also don't print.

Comment: So here's something that works for a little while: decreasing the number of wanderers from 100 to 5. The program will execute as it should for a little while, and then trip up with either a bus error. Could it be that my wanderers are stepping off of the canvas and that's what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code but as per your last comment, "stepping of the canvas" i think i can see that you have a couple of situations where you might be trying to access data out of range in both your "hidden" mat and "image" mats.

Afraid i can only offer sugestions

```
void Agent::Draw(Mat image) {
  int * location = GetLocation();
  int * color = GetReveal();
  for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++) {
    image.data[image.step[0]*location[0] + image.step[1]*location[1] + i] = color[i];
  }
}
```

Here your accessing GetLocation which has been instantiated from a random number times the size of the hidden mat during the construction of the Agent. I would worry that here your going to get an "index out of bounds" type error when accessing the image.data matrix. So this might be the first thing to check.

Like wise in

```
int * Agent::GetReveal(void) {
  int * BGR = new int[3];
  location = GetLocation();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    BGR[i] = hidden.data[hidden.step[0]*location[0] + hidden.step[1]*location[1] + i];
  }
  return (BGR);
}
```

you using getLocation() which is going to return a point far larger than the size of the hidden image. So i'm pretty sure you get an error here as well. location should be derived from the hidden.cols() and hidden.rows().

Only had a glancing look, but i would definitely put some checks in around the values getLocation() is returning, and if such a value is accessible from the mat matrices.

Additionally, although i'm not entirely sure, as i think your using location in two different ways, but if location is a point somewhere in your Draw(image) then you would need to adjust the following:

```
location[0] += (((location[0] + dx >= 0) & (location[0] + dx < hidden.cols)) ? dx : 0);
location[1] += (((location[1] + dy >= 0) & (location[1] + dy < hidden.rows)) ? dy : 0);
```

and take into account the width of the hidden image, something like

```
location[0] += (((location[0] + dx >= 0) & (location[0] + dx + hidden.cols < maxWidth)) ? dx : 0);
location[1] += (((location[1] + dy >= 0) & (location[1] + dy + hidden.rows < maxHeight)) ? dy : 0);
```

where maxWidth and maxHeight are the width of your image.

Hope that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Still trying to better understand what your aiming to achieve, so sorry if the above isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Linux environment, you can use valgrind to find out exactly where the segmentation fault is happening. Just type valgrind before the name of the program, or the way you execute your program. For example, if you execute your program with the following command:

hello -print

issue the following command instead:

valgrind hello -print